# Please provide information on duplicate question relationships in SEDE again

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, data-explorer

Before the changes to how duplicates are displayed earlier this month, it was possible to get data on duplicate questions and their "originals" out of SEDE by parsing the automatically inserted string. It wasn't pretty (or fast), but it worked, well enough to verify information provided by the team, and even correct it: [1](http://meta.superuser.com/revisions/6300/2), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/165936/4).

---

The newest SU data set is February 10, well after the changes went live. One question closed as duplicate in that time frame is [this one](https://superuser.com/q/547081), and there's nothing in Data Explorer linking it to the original: The duplicate message is no longer a prefix edited into the post, and therefore no longer queryable at all:

- `Posts` has no `DuplicatePostId` or something like it pointing to the linked question
- There's nothing useful in `PostHistory` for the closed question other than *it was closed* and by whom
- The `Votes` table has nothing either, and doesn't even mention a reason (like *duplicate*, *off topic*, ...)

---

**Please provide a way to determine duplicate question relationships in Data Explorer again.**

Answer (score 4):

This has been completed thanks to the `PostLinks` table in SEDE. `RelatedPostId` is the duplicate target and `PostId` is the post that was marked as a duplicate. (Provided that `LinkTypeId = 3`.)

See the full documentation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/213671).