# SEDE query to find question with most duplicates pointing at it?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, data-explorer

I just saw this question:

[What is the most rampant duplicate on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9686/252153)

Is there an SEDE query to find this? I seem to remember there being a page of "questions linked to this" for each question, but I can't find that page now, and I'd like to aggregate the data, with a query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: I just found this query that does what you want:

[Posts that are the targets of the most duplicate closures](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/315074/posts-that-are-the-target-of-the-most-duplicate-closures). On Meta, currently, it seems [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997) is winning!

---

> I seem to remember there being a page of "questions linked to this"
> for each question, but I can't find that page now...

If you want to find all the questions linked to a specific question (not necessarily dupes), the URL would be:

```
http://[site]/questions/linked/QUESTION_ID
```

So for this question, it would be:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/256607
```

Comment: This query no longer seems to be working; I get zero output rows for all the parameters I have tried (in particular I was hoping to find [tag:python] duplicates on Stack Overflow).

Comment: ... I guess maybe related to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167621/please-provide-information-on-duplicate-question-relationships-in-sede-again

Answer (score 4):

This query by @AndrewLeach works with the current SEDE schema:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/223260/most-popular-duplicate-targets-by-tag